# How can you set skining like upSkin,downSkin,overSkin to Accordion in flex?

Tags: css, apache-flex, flash, flex3, air

In my project i used Accordion . if i add skin to Accordion then so error ? but i tried like

```
<mx:Accordion  borderStyle="solid" width="212" height="346" upSkin="@Embed(source='image/UPDATE.png')" >
```

But shows error like Cannot resolve attribute 'upSkin' for component type mx.containers.Accordion. how can i add overskin,downskin,upskin to Accordion in flex ? please refer me

Answer (score 0):

There is no "upskin" property for an accordion which explains the error you are getting. The following example shows how you can create a very custom accordion which should enable you to achieve the effect you desire, http://dougmccune.com/blog/2007/09/22/nifty-flex-accordion-menu-like-on-applecom/

This example was referred to in another stack overflow answer, 
[flex 3 accordion component and rounded corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/482769/flex-3-accordion-component-and-rounded-corners)